# Find time offset between two sets of sensordata

Tags: python

I have Data of two Sensors, which measure the same value. One of them in a high frequency, the other one only every few minutes. Each of them has a separate timestamp. They seem to have a slight time offset of a few seconds. How can calculate the time offset and correct it?

Comment: How would you do it without Python?

Comment: Plot curves, look at peaks or interesting points and move the curve along the x-axis, untill they align

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.